How Can I Implement Server-Side Rendering (SSR) in My React Project for SEO?
I'm working on a React project and want to implement Server-Side Rendering (SSR) to ensure that search engines like Google can read my content for better SEO and ranking. I need guidance on how to set up SSR properly in React. I’ve tried using hydrateRoot, but it doesn’t seem to be working for my project.
Could you provide code examples and a clear method for implementing SSR?

What methods or code have you tried? Do you have any code to share? so i can help you.

This question is very broad. Which steps have you taken so far? Which errors did you encounter? There are many ways to go about SSR with React, highly depending on how your backend is implemented.

You have 2 option if you want to SSR in your react project

Used Nextjs
Used express and react-dom-server

But i suggest Nextjs is convenient option
for 2 option used express and react-dom-server
this way you can achive
Add the following code to server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const App = require('./src/App').default;  // Adjust path if App.js is 
located elsewhere

const app = express();

// Serve static files from the 'build' directory
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  // Render the App component to a string
  const appHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);

  // Generate the full HTML response
  const html = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
  scale=1.0">
    <title>Your SSR React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">${appHtml}</div>
    <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
    `;

 // Send the response
  res.send(html);
 });

 // Start the server
  app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running on 
    http://localhost:3000'));

Enable Hydration on the Client Side
import React from 'react';
import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client'; // `hydrateRoot` 
ensures client-side functionality
import App from './App';

hydrateRoot(document.getElementById('root'), <App />);


If you want to SSR in your react project.You have to use Next.js library.
Documentation

This is inclomplete. Next.js is one framework supporting SSR for React, but it is not the only way to render React on the server side.

You're right. However, in this case, let's agree that moving the react project to next is the most effective method.

I do not agree. Without knowing the markup of their backend it is not possible to make a recommendation here.
